# Make a dictionary value non-optional as extension

Tags: swift, dictionary, null, swift3, option-type

The below playground outlines my issue. The extension will remove nil values from my dictionary, but leave the other values as Optional(Value). What I need is a dictionary that has no nil values and make the optional value type non-optional.

Ex: I have a dictionary of `[String:Int?]`. I want the `jsonSantize()` of that called on that dictionary to return a `[String:Int]`.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import Foundation


protocol OptionalType {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    var asOptional : Wrapped? { get }
}

extension Optional : OptionalType {
    var asOptional : Wrapped? {
        return self
    }
}

extension Dictionary where Value : OptionalType{

    //Sanitizes the current dictionary for json serialization
    //Removes nil values entirely. Makes optionals non-optional
    func jsonSanitize() -> Dictionary<Key,Value> {
        var newDict:[Key:Value] = [:]
        for (key, value) in self {
            if value.asOptional != nil {
                newDict.updateValue(self[key]!, forKey: key)
            }
        }
        return newDict
    }

}

var youGood = false

var stringMan:String? = youGood ?
    "WOHOO!" :
    nil

var dict:[String:Any?] = [
    "stuff":"THINGIES",
    "things": stringMan

]
var dict2 = dict.jsonSanitize()
print(dict2)

var test = (stringMan != nil)
```

UPDATE: Suggestion made to use Value.Wrapped as new dictionary type

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import Foundation


protocol OptionalType {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    var asOptional : Wrapped? { get }
}

extension Optional : OptionalType {
    var asOptional : Wrapped? {
        return self
    }
}

extension Dictionary where Value : OptionalType{

    //Sanitizes the current dictionary for json serialization
    //Removes nil values entirely. Makes optionals non-optional
    func jsonSanitize() -> Dictionary<Key,Value.Wrapped> {
        var newDict:[Key:Value.Wrapped] = [:]
        for (key, value) in self {
            if let v = value.asOptional {
                newDict.updateValue(v, forKey: key)
            }
        }
        return newDict
    }

}

var youGood = false

var stringMan:String? = youGood ?
    "WOHOO!" :
    nil

var dict:[String:Any?] = [
    "stuff":"THINGIES",
    "things": stringMan

]
var dict2:[String:Any] = dict.jsonSanitize()
print(dict2)

var test = (stringMan != nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method produces a dictionary of the same type `[Key: Value]`
with `Value` being some optional type. What you probably want is
to produce a dictionary of type `[Key: Value.Wrapped]`:

```
extension Dictionary where Value: OptionalType {

    func jsonSanitize() -> [Key: Value.Wrapped] {
        var newDict: [Key: Value.Wrapped] = [:]
        for (key, value) in self {
            if let v = value.asOptional {
                newDict.updateValue(v, forKey: key)
            }
        }
        return newDict
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let dict: [String: Int?] = [
    "foo": 1234,
    "bar": nil
]
var dict2 = dict.jsonSanitize()
print(dict2) // ["foo": 1234]
```

Note also that of **Swift 3.0.1/Xcode 8.1 beta,** optionals
are bridged to `NSNull` instances automatically, see

- [SE-0140  – Warn when Optional converts to Any, and bridge Optional As Its Payload Or NSNull](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0140-bridge-optional-to-nsnull.md)

Comment: Using your above solution, I still get a dictionary with ["stuff": Optional("THINGIES")] in my given example.

Comment: @steventnorris: That is strange. I have tested it with exactly your example, and the output is `["stuff": "THINGIES"]`.

Comment: I've added my code above. Probably missing something small. The print(dict2) currently shows ["stuff": Optional("THINGIES")]

Comment: You're right. I missed the let. Huh, does the let unwrap the thing? If that's the case, how is that different than casting with as! Value.Wrapped?

Comment: @steventnorris: I might have to do with the `Any` type, that won't happen for a `[String:String?]` dictionary. Anyway, optional binding is good, forced casting is bad :)

Comment: Fair enough. It has it's place when you're absolutely certain of the type. Swift has typing issues in my opinion, just in general as a language. That seems to work for me now though using the let.